# What dropped for me during for the "20 years of StarCraft" random drops on Twitch?

Tags: starcraft-2, twitch

Blizzard has it's [20 years of StarCraft](https://starcraft2.com/en-us/sc20) event going on, where [twitch drops can happen for watching games of StarCraft on twitch](https://starcraft2.com/en-us/news/21590508). After (presumably) 2 hours of watching, I earned my Bob Toss awards. This was expected.

The announcement pages also say "Watch any [SC] streams...a chance for a random StarCraft II announcer or co-op commander drop". So I kept watching hoping to get some more co-op commanders (or maybe some cool announcers or something).

Much later (this morning), I earned something *else* on twitch, but it looks like a generic SC20 logo.[image]
(The first thing everyone gets after watching 2 hours on Twitch) So, I'm not sure what I won. I logged in, but there wasn't an achievement or any other kind of toast. I have a couple of announcers and commanders already, so I'm not sure what's new. (I think they all came from other purchases e.g. Nova announcer from the Covert Ops pack? and commanders from various other Blizzard purchases.) How do I find out what I won?

Comment: Do you have your Battle.net and Twitch accounts linked?

Comment: @Nzall Yes. I don't think drops happen without the link, but even so, I received the bob toss portrait and spray already in my account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [RSS Feed for StarCraft 2 News](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/feed/news) ([the related article](https://us.battle.net/en/blog/21590508) was a 404), it stated:

> WEEKLY DROPS:
> Watch any Twitch channel streaming StarCraft, StarCraft: Remastered, or StarCraft II beginning March 6 for a chance to earn a random StarCraft II announcer or Co-op Commander drop. Each week, a new collection of announcers and Co-op Commanders will be available as random drops, so be sure to tune in regularly.
>
> - WEEK 1 (3/6 – 3/12): Commander: Karax, Announcer: Raynor, Announcer: Swann
> - WEEK 2 (3/13 – 3/19): Commander: Vorazun, Announcer: Abathur, Announcer: Kerrigan
> - WEEK 3 (3/20 – 3/26): Commander: Swann, Announcer: Alarak, Announcer: Artanis
> - WEEK 4 [5X Bonus*] (3/27 – 4/6): Commander: Zagara + all previous Announcers from Weeks 1-3
>
> When: March 6 – April 6, 2018 (see list for exact dates)
> Where: Any Twitch channel streaming StarCraft, StarCraft: Remastered, or StarCraft II

Answer (score 3):

The Protoss painter is the entire set of BobToss, he'll be available as a spray, emoji and skin.

The one on the right is a generic drop. There is no way to tell from Twitch or the icon what you got. You have to literally search everywhere to find out what you got. There are people talking about this very issue in the comment section [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/82oeic/got_2_drops_watching_nate_and_demuslim/)

Comment: The things you mention in the first paragraph (interface skins, portrait, decal, skins) are things I got before the first drop.
My question is specifically for the twitch drops, of which you haven't mentioned anything, unless you are meaning "check out your skins for your units and buildings", but I don't really know what i'm looking for as I already have some skins.

Comment: @McKay Sorry about that, I updated the answer specifically stating about Twitch Drops and a link that will tell you more information about them. The rest of my answer covers everything else about the rewards for the 20th anniversary.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the question specifically stating about the random chance drops that are mentioned in the link, because I want more information about what I got.